# How to move through a graph that has a Set of Strings

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this bit of code to work properly. I'm supposed to take a one line file and move through a graph and output each state for a specific input number.
[image]

The sample file would have something like:
Start; 1; 0; 1; 1; 0; 1

And the output would be:

input = 1; state = ArraySet[start]

input = 0; state = ArraySet[start, near]

input = 1; state = ArraySet[start, end]

input = 1; state = ArraySet[start]

input = 0; state = ArraySet[start, near]

input = 1; state = ArraySet[start,end]

I completed the code below.

```
public class NDFA {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Map<String, Map<String,Set<String>>> mainMap = new ArrayMap<String, Map<String,Set<String>>>();

  TypedBufferReader input = new TypedBufferReader("Enter Non-Deterministic Finite Automaton Description File: ");


  for (;;) {
     try {
          String line = input.readLine();
          StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
          String  state = st.nextToken();

          Map<String,Set<String>> transitions = mainMap.get(state);

          transitions = new ArrayMap<String, Set<String>>();
          Set<String> stateSet = new ArraySet<String>();

          while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
              String intStateInput = st.nextToken();
              String inputState = st.nextToken();
              stateSet.add(inputState);
              transitions.put(intStateInput, stateSet);
          }
        mainMap.put(state, transitions);
     } catch (EOFException e) { break;}
  }

//sort
List<String> mapList = new ArrayList<String>(mainMap.keys());
Collections.sort(mapList);
System.out.println("Non-Deterministic Finite Automaton");
for (String s : mapList) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> tempMap = mainMap.get(s);
    System.out.println(s + " transitions = " + tempMap.toString());
}

//Process one line file.
  TypedBufferReader oneLineInput = new TypedBufferReader("Enter start state/inputs file: ");

  try {
      String oneLine = oneLineInput.readLine();
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(oneLine,";");
      String currentState = st.nextToken();
      System.out.println("Initial state = " + currentState);
      String inputNum = "";

      Set<String> inputSet;

             //stuck while storing inputNums in a set.
      while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
          inputNum = st.nextToken();
          inputSet.add(inputNum);
          Map<String,Set<String>> transitions = mainMap.get(currentState);
          currentState = transitions.get(inputSet.values());
          System.out.println("input = " + inputNum + "; new state = " + currentState) ;
      }
      System.out.println("Final state = " + currentState);
  } catch (EOFException e) {}

  }

}
```

I can't get the current state to output any correct set. I can easily verify the input numbers but going from start to near to end confuses me and I can't output the correct ArraySet.

Comment: "a bit jammed" doesn't explain what your problem is. Second, I don't understand the format ` Start; 1; 0; 1; 1; 0; 1` - what does it mean ?

Comment: The algorithm would start at the current state of "start" then the current state would move based on the integer value. For example, from start it would go to itself, then to near, then to end, then back to start. And so on until it reaches the final current state of end.

Comment: What does the arc labeled `0,1` mean?  Why isn't this followed for the second input?  Also, please post the NDFA definition file.

Comment: It sounds to me like this specific automata will get into an infinite loop since `input = 0; state = ArraySet[start, near]` will always branch out. Anyways, you can't read the input file with `while` loop - you need a recursive method that will call itself for any input, and if needed, it will make more than one call (in the non-deterministic situations).

Comment: @JimGarrison NDFA is a non-deterministic finite automata.

Comment: Really? I did one for Finite Automata using the while loop to read another file. I'd imagine it would still work for this.

Comment: How is this question of interest to the community?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar before in python. Not sure if this helps with your java.

```
>>> g = {}
>>> g['start'] = {1: ['start'], 0: ['start', 'near']}
>>> g['near'] = {1: ['end']}
>>> g['end'] = {}
>>> data = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
>>> states = ['start']
>>> while data:
...     x = data.pop(0)
...     new_states = []
...     for s in states:
...         reach = g[s]
...         if x in reach:
...             new_states += reach[x]
...     states = list(set(new_states))
...     print states
...
['start', 'near']
['start', 'end']
['start']
['start', 'near']
['start', 'end']
```

Comment: Definitely helpful but not too familiar with python.